# Is it possible to add a location/folder on my hard disk to sources.list?

Tags: apt, dpkg, software-sources

Is it possible to add a location/folder on my hard disk (ex: `/media/Data/Ubuntu`) to the `sources.list`? If yes,how?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are 4 steps to setting up a simple repository for yourself:

1. Install `dpkg-dev`.
2. Put the packages in a directory.
3. Create a script that will scan the packages and create a file `apt-get update` can read.
4. Add a line to your `sources.list` pointing at your repository.

### Install `dpkg-dev`

Type in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

### The Directory

Create a directory where you will keep your packages.

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/Data/Ubuntu
```

Now move your packages into the directory you've just created.

### The Script `update-mydebs`

It's a simple three-liner:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /media/Data/Ubuntu
dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

Cut and paste the above into gedit, and save it as `update-mydebs` in `~/bin` (the tilde `~` means your home directory. If `~/bin` does not exist, create it: Ubuntu will put that directory in your `PATH`. It's a good place to put personal scripts). Next, make the script executable:

```
chmod u+x ~/bin/update-mydebs
```

### `sources.list`

Add the line:

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:/media/Data/Ubuntu ./
```

to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and you're done.

### Using the Repository

Whenever you put a new deb in the `mydebs` directory, run

```
sudo update-mydebs
sudo apt-get update
```

Now your local packages can be manipulated with Synaptic, `aptitude` and the `apt` commands: `apt-get`, `apt-cache`, etc. When you attempt to `apt-get install`, any dependencies will be resolved for you, as long as they can be met.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply. I appreciate your time taken to help me (and the fellow linux users).

Comment: Hi Sylvian, just one more question: I have two folders called "Main" and "Contrib" in the folder where the packages are stored. What should be the line added to the sources.list? What does this **(./)** command do? Thanks!

Comment: As of 2020, you may need to add a trusted specifier to your sources.list
`deb [trusted=yes]  file:/media/Data/Ubuntu ./`