# deb file repositry fails during apt-get update due to not having a Release file

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I previously created two folders full of .debs and followed [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458748/is-it-possible-to-add-a-location-folder-on-my-hard-disk-to-sources-list) question to be able to add them to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file: by doing to following:

```
cd ~/me/debs
dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
echo "deb file:/home/me/debs ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

However now when I went to create another folder and reload the repos with `sudo apt-get update` I get the following errors.

```
Get:6 file:/home/me/debs ./ Release
Err:6 file:/home/me/debs ./ Release
  File not found - /home/me/debs/./Release (2: No such file or directory)
E: The repository 'file:/home/me/debs ./ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have tried creating the Release file using touch, however the error changes to: `E: The repository 'file:/home/me/debs ./ Release' is not signed.` after it tries to find a Releases.gpg file.

All posts I've seen with this error have to deal with acutal sources that aren't local, and I wonder if there's some way I allow apt to include the repo without having a Releases file.

Answer (score 3):

A working solution was to add `[trusted=yes]` to the line:

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:/home/me/debs ./
```